# Homologous tori in 4-manifold

Tags: geometric-topology

Let $X$ be a 4-manifold and $T$, $S$ two tori embedded in $X$. Let $m_1$, $l_1$ and $m_2$, $l_2$ be loops in $X$ generating $H_1$ of $T$ and $S$, respectively (where I am identifying the tori with their images in $X$). Suppose that $m_1$ and $m_2$, and $l_1$ and $l_2$ are homotopic in X, respectively. Does it follow that $T$ and $S$ represent homologous elements in H_2(X)?

I would like to use that $m_1$, $m_2$, and $l_1$, $l_2$ bound annuli in $X$ (is this correct?) to construct a map $S^1\times S^1\times I \to X$ with $S^1\times S^1\times 0 \to T$, and $S^1\times S^1\times 1\to S$. But I can't see how to do this.

(I had previously mistakenly posted this without specifying the dimension of X.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't follow.

(I'm taking all of this from the bottom of page 19 in Terry Lawson's survey "The Minimal Genus" which can be found [here](http://math.ucr.edu/~res/inprogress/mingenus.pdf).  What follows is almost an exact copy of his argument, but specialized to the example at hand.)

Let $X = S^2\times S^2$.  Take $a=[S^2\times \{p\}]$ and $b=[\{p\}\times S^2]$ as generators for $H_2(X)$.  Consider the element $2a+2a\in H_2(X)$.  I claim that this is represented by an embedded $T^2$.

Believing the for a second, we can find another $T^2$ in $X$ which is not homologous to this first $T^2$, just look at $T^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow X$ where the first map is any embeding and the second map is a chart map.  Since this maps factors through $\mathbb{R}^4$, it's null homologous.  This implies the two $T^2$s are not homologous to each other.  Nevertheless, since $X$ is simply connected, the condition on your generating curves $m_1, l_1$, etc. is satisfied.

Here's how to construct the embedding.  Pick two distinct points, $\{p,q\}\subseteq S^2$ and consider $S^2\times \{p\} \cup S^2\times \{q\} \cup \{p\}\times S^2\cup \{q\}\times S^2 := M_p\cup M_q\cup N_p\cup N_q$ which clearly represents $2a + 2b$.  Notice that $M_p\cap M_q = N_p\cap N_q = \emptyset$ but we have $M_i \cap N_j = \{(i,j)\}$ for $i \in \{p,q\}$ and likewise for $j$.  So, there are 4 intersection points: $\{(p,p), (p,q), (q,p), (q,q)\}$.)

Connect sum $M_p$ and $N_p$ at the point $(p,p)$.  Since $M_p$ and $N_p$ were spheres, this connect sum is still a sphere.  But now we've cut out the "bad" point and replaced it with an embedded tube.

I claim the new thing represents the same homology class as the original union of the 4 spheres. The point is that the natural map $M_p\sharp N_p\rightarrow M_p\vee N_p$ (the one point union) carries the fundamental class $[M_p\sharp N_p]$ to $[M_p]+[N_p]\in H_2(M_p \vee N_p) \cong H_2(M_p)\oplus H_2(N_p)$.  So, at least as homology is concerned, the inclusion map of $M_p\sharp N_p$ into $X$ factors through the map $M_p\sharp N_p\rightarrow M_p\vee N_p$.

Likewise, connect sum at all the other intersection points **except** $(q,q)$.  At this stage one has an immersed sphere representing $2a+2b$.  This sphere is *not* embedded as it has a double point: $(q,q)$.  Finally, "connect sum" (i.e., do surgery) there.  In this case, the two neighborhoods removed are from the same sphere, so after gluing in the tube, one gets $T^2$ which is now embedded.

$$ $$

Finally, if one wants to do this on $X = \mathbb{C}P^2$ (as per our original discussion), consider the element $1\in H_2(\mathbb{C}P^2)$ represented by, say, the sphere $S^2 = \{[z_0:z_1:0]\in \mathbb{C}P^2\}$.  Then the element $3$ is represented by $\{[z_0:z_1:0]\} \cup  \{[z_0:0:z_1]\} \cup \{[0:z_1:z_2]\}$.  Each of these 3 sets is an $S^2$ and any two of them intersect in a single point (either $[1:0:0], [0:1:0],$ or $[0:0:1]$).  One does the same construction as above to get an embedded torus representing $3\in H_2(\mathbb{C}P^2)$.

Comment: I learned a whole lot while trying to adapt my argument from your previous question to this!  Thanks for posing the question, it was tons of fun!